# Cross Frame Script Reuse

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, unobtrusive-javascript, pagespeed

I have an application running in a HTA (MSFT HTML Application) that uses the same script file over and over again throughout frames; as this hits 9 in places and as the application is setup within various servers with caching set to immediate expire I'm trying to carve out some sort of performance in this ball of mud.

Is there a 'good' way to load the main script file in the top frame then excuting it within the frames i.e.

--- TOP WINDOW ----

```
var MainScript = function(){  return (function(){ all current functions etc here })(); };
```

--- SUB Frames ----

```
var FrameScript = top.MainScript;
FrameScript();
```

And how would this be affected by window scope (would it keep the top window scope or be in scope of the frame-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method appears to be to give the subframe an ID then to dynamically populate it with the script loaded in the master frame (using eval to make the js run);

i.e.

|> **Parent (aka TOP Frame)**

```
<script>top.windows = [];</script>
<script id="MyScript">
    var test = function(){ top.windows.push(window); }
</script>
```

|>> **SubFrame**
Loads SubSubFrame in an IFrame

|>>> **SubSubFrame**

```
<script id="SF1">
document.getElementById("SF1").innerHTML = eval(top.window.document.getElementById("MyScript").innerHTML);
test();
</script>
```

This Works upto and beyond 8 frames deep within a trusted domain (in a .hta you set application=true on the frames for this)

I used top.windows[] so I could check the scope. (type it into console.log(top.windows) in firebug)

Nausiating and deep; Google do something similar to delay JS loading/execution.

- http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/09/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-reducing.html
- http://blog.sproutcore.com/post/225219087/faster-loading-through-eval

Comment: That approach removes the repeated round-trips to the server, but still repeatedly `eval`s the same javascript.  It'd be more efficient to load the js library in the top-level window, and call its functions directly (or use `apply`,`call`,or `bind` if you need them called in the context of the frame window object).

Comment: @Doin as it was 3 years ago; and as anyone implementing a system this badly deserves to go bust. I'm inclined not to care :D
For the sake of clarity each subframe was customizable (at an xml level) for various workflows etc and the scripts had to execute in the context of the subframe. Its possible to do this by calling the parent lib and passing the window as the reference but the sheer quantity of shit JS in this site made the above a simpler fix/implementation (without rewriting 50K+ lines of bad JS)